# How to extend or add data to cdk-steps in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm new to Angular and the CDK. I try to implement my own `cdk-stepper`, e.g. `my-stepper`. I want to give each `cdk-step` a couple of properties that I can access in `my-stepper`, for example text for a next-step-button. How can that be done? Can I make a directive to add to the `cdk-step`s?

```
<my-stepper linear>
        <cdk-step [completed]="stepCompleted" nextButtonText="I want to use this in my-stepper">
            <my-control></ny-control>
        </cdk-step>
</app-gus-stepper>
```

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this issue?  I have run into the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 1):

You can define your custom *stepper* and *step* components as following:

**stepper.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkStepper } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { NgForOf } from '@angular/common';
import { StepComponent } from './step.component';
@Component({  
    selector: 'app-stepper',
    template: `<div *ngFor="let step of steps">  {{ step.nextButtonText }} </div>`,
    standalone: true,
    imports: [NgForOf],  
    providers: [
        { provide: CdkStepper, useExisting: StepperComponent }
    ]
})
export class StepperComponent extends CdkStepper {  
    @ContentChildren(StepComponent, { descendants: true }) override _steps!: QueryList<StepComponent>;  
    @ContentChildren(StepComponent, { descendants: false })  override steps!: QueryList<StepComponent>;
}
```

**step.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkStep } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
@Component({  
    selector: 'app-step',  
    template: '<ng-template><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>',  
    standalone: true,  
    providers: [
        { provide: CdkStep, useExisting: StepComponent }
    ]
})
export class StepComponent extends CdkStep {  
    @Input() nextButtonText = '';
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<app-stepper>  
    <app-step nextButtonText="text">test content</app-step>
</app-stepper>
```